# How To Load Plist Into Multiple Table Views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk, plist

I made a data.plist and want to load the root array (names) into a table view, then when you click on each cell, it will load their corresponding exercise array into a new table view.  How would I implement this method into my TableViewController?

My current plist has a root array, with a dictionary item for each muscle group (Item 0, then child name) then contains an array for the muscle's exercises.

My didSelectRowAtIndexPath Method for the first table that pushes the 2nd view subtable is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    ExerciseTableViewController *detailViewController = [[ExerciseTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AbdominalTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
```

My viewDidLoad method for the 2nd table view controller (this needs to be fixed) is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

if (exerciseArray == nil)
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"biceps" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.exerciseArray = array;
    [array release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming i understand you question.

You can do something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *muscle = [muscles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  //'muscles' array is the first level of your plist
    ...
    ExerciseTableViewController *detailViewController = [[ExerciseTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:muscle bundle:nil];

    detailViewController.muscle = muscle;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
    ...
}
```

And in the second controller:

```
    ...
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"biceps" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.exerciseArray = [plistDict objectForKey:muscle];   //'muscle' is the string you set in the previous controller
    [plistDict release];
    ...
```

Hope it's help.

*Edit after Faisal comment:*

Using the following plist file:
[image: Data.plist]
For read this plist you can do:

```
//Read the plist file into an array (the root element is an array)
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *rootLevel = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Then for read the second level, the 'rootLevel' content:

```
NSDictionary *secondLevel = [rootLevel objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *muscle = [secondLevel valueForKey:@"name"];    //"Biceps" string
NSArray *exercises = [secondLevel valueForKey:@"exercises"];    //[exercises objectAtIndex:0] is "Biceps Curl" string
```

Comment: Thanks GojaN.  You can see the plist I have now and the plist I want to use here at bottom of page (can't post pics on this site).[link](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1120321) So would the code you posted work with the new plist I have made?

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I am getting an error for in the ExercisesTableViewController, "Use of undeclared identifier 'rootLevel') even though I referenced the class MuscleTableViewController and tried importing MuslceTableViewController.h also

Comment: I have also attached my code here in a zip file if its any easier to look at, thanks! http://www.box.net/shared/static/kf7rhhm6ji.zip

Comment: Faisal. That error is because you copy/paste the code without understand it. 'rootLevel' is a local variable and exist only in the place that you declare it. You must read the Data.plist file in the first controller and pass the '[rootLevel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]' element to the second one.